# Obtener un número de una consulta MySQL con CodeIgniter

Tags: mysql, codeigniter

Buenas tardes tengo un problema con una consulta MySQL, estoy utilizando CodeIgniter , esta es mi consulta que tengo y jala bien.

```
public function grafica_calls($date_inicio, $date_fin) {
  try {   
    $query = $this->db->query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM cdr WHERE calldate BETWEEN '".$date_inicio."' AND '".$date_fin."'");

  if ($query->num_rows() <= 0)
    return null;
  else
    return $query->result();
  } catch(Exception $e) {
    show_error($e->getMessage() . ' --- ' . $e->getTraceAsString());
  }
}
```

En mi controlado obtengo el resultado en el siguiente arreglo.

```
$data['date_uno'] = $this->login_model->grafica_calls($date_inicio, $date_fin);
```

Y cuando lo imprimir me mestra lo siguiente

```
print_r($data['date_uno']);
```

**Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [COUNT(*)] => 0 ) )**

Mi problema es como obtengo únicamente el “0” que me está mandando la consulta

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Únicamente como consejo ya que usas Codeigniter porque no le sacas provecho al [Active Record](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide2/database/active_record.html) para hacer tus métodos en los modelos, tu método por ejemplo quedaría de la siguiente manera:

```
function grafica_calls($date_inicio, $date_fin) {
        try {
            return $this->db 
                        ->select("COUNT(*) as total")
                        ->where("calldate BETWEEN '".$date_inicio."' AND '".$date_fin."'",null)
                        ->get("cdr")
                        ->row();

        } catch (Exception $e) {
            show_error($e->getMessage() . ' --- ' . $e->getTraceAsString());
        }
    }
```

¿Cual es la ventaja? A parte que te apegas al estándar en Codeigniter no sería necesario usar  `$query->num_rows()` ya que con la expresión `row()` te aseguras de devolver solo una fila. Puedes ver también: [Generating Query Results](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/results.html) para tener más claro de cuando usar `row()` y cuando usar `result()`.

Lo que obtengas de esto:

```
$data['date_uno'] = $this->login_model->grafica_calls($date_inicio, $date_fin);
```

Lo muestras en tu vista así: `$date_uno->total;`

Espero pueda aportar en algo.

Comment: No me sale nada, esta vacio y se supone que yo estoy trayendo un 0

Comment: @Javierfr resulto supongo

Answer (score 1):

Así quedaría tu consulta

```
$query = $this->db->query("SELECT COUNT(*) AS total FROM cdr WHERE calldate BETWEEN '".$date_inicio."' AND '".$date_fin."'");
```

Para obtener ese valor en la vista lo imprimes así

```
echo $date_uno->total
```

Comment: No me imprime el 0

Comment: No me sale nada, esta vacio y se supone que yo estoy trayendo un 0

Comment: ¿Te funciona bien la consulta?